# distinct count subject when filter sum raw data greater than powerbi dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

distinct count subject when filter sum raw data greater than powerbi dax

i need to calculate subject with raw data grater than 5
i used if in matrix work but when i put in card only read 1

PO5 = if(Act[act_]>=5,1,0)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/563j9.png)

its my raw data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72SRB.png)

hopefully anyone can help me